# In python, is it possible to drop specific columns from a pivot?

Tags: python, pivot-table, drop

I have a pivot with company name, and profit from 1990 to 1999. I'm trying to calculate top 20 profits between 1990 and 1999. I'm getting a key error with the below code. It doesnt matter if there are NaN in the years between.

Any advice?

`Profits_1990_to_1999_pivot.dropna(subset=['1990','1999'])`

Comment: Have you checked whether `dropna` has an `errors` argument?

Comment: Can you share the Structure of your data?

Comment: Hi, I finally figured it out, dropped the data using pivot.dropna(subset=pivot.columns[[9]]) & pivot.dropna(subset=pivot.columns[[0]])